# Limit on throughput to upload single S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading a single large file to S3 (> 1GB) and cannot get throughput over 250MB/sec regardless of instance class.

I've checked all the obvious things: I have a VPC endpoint, I am using multipart upload (via AWS CLI `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 sync`), and the instance has ENA enabled.

What's more, I can upload *multiple* files in parallel and achieve an aggregate bandwidth > 500MB/sec, effectively saturating my EBS volume's throughput, but I cannot get the same bandwidth on a single file.

I do not see any evidence of throttling with `--debug` output.

Support hasn't found an answer for me yet either, so I'm wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing with a limit on how quickly you can upload to a single object.

Comment: Have you verified that `aws s3 cp` uses multiple threads, and/or has multiple concurrent connections to the S3 endpoint? For the latter, `sudo netstat -anop | grep PID` should show multiple "ESTABLISHED" connections, and the last column (which is undocumented) should change between runs.

Comment: Yes it is using multiple connections/threads.  The `sudo netstat` command above shows 10 lines, which is default for max_concurrent_requests, and if I change that parameter the number of lines from netstat changes

Comment: Seems like there must be some OS-level configuration that exists to keep one process from monopolizing the network, but I have no idea what it might be. Good luck.